# Do work when TabPage is selected without causing paint to lag/delay

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to do brief work (< 300ms) when a certain TabPage is selected in a given TabControl.  Currently I execute the worker method when the TabPage is selected, but the TabPage does not paint until the work finishes, and so the TabPage looks funky/garbled for a brief moment until the work method completes and the TabPage paints properly.  I understand that this is happening because I'm doing work in the same thread that is drawing the TabPage.  However, I'm looking for a simple way to prevent this "ugly" behavior without doing the work in a separate thread.  Using a separate thread for this situation really feels like overkill.  I would prefer to workaround the situation by somehow allowing the TabPage to finish painting before the worker method is executed.  Any ideas?

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["myTabPage"])
    {                
        doWorkFor300ms();                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to force a refresh before you do the work, without a separate thread...then:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["myTabPage"])
    {                
        this.Refresh();
        Application.DoEvents();
        doWorkFor300ms();                
    }
}
```